# Autocomplete results via JSON in Android

Tags: android

I'm getting API results via an AsyncTask and using that to populate a dropdown which generates an AutoComplete. I'm using the onTextChanged method in TextWatcher on an AutoCompleteTextView and calling the AsyncTask when the string is greater than 2 characters.

I get some performance issues when there are a lot of characters pressed in a query. It also causes my API key to get rate limited every once in awhile.

I'd like to limit it for calling the AsyncTask only when the user pauses typing - is there any way to do that? Anything else I can do to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

Give some delay time, before start asynctask

if user react in that time, renew delay time again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - [setAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setAdapter%28T%29)

Worked very good for me